# Error on rename 'x.frm' to 'y.frm' - Errcode: 13 - Permission denied - MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, runtime-error

Ok, I know there is *so many* questions about this issue but, since I could not find a answer to solve my problem (I tried so many many many workarounds!!) and it made me to waste 4 hours of my work, and now I found where my problem were in, I would like to share and keep here also for my own future reference.

#### The problem

`Error on rename of '.\db_testes\#sql-1f1c_1a.frm' to '.\db_testes\alteracaocrono_ateste.frm' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)` that was happening when creating an index in a MySQL table just after to create it.

Why is this **SO** strange?
1. Because it was happening in a script were I had so many others 'create table's and 'create index' that were working fine just before the error happen;
2. Because everytime I tried it after cleaning the database to run it again, that error occurred in a different place, a different index each time!;
3. Because all folders related to MySQL had FULL-CONTROLL permissions for 'everybody' (I was desperate, I know);

Checking `perror 13` I was getting 'Win32 - the data is invalid'. No much informative at all.

#### What I had tried

1. Change the `tmpdir` of MySQL (in mysql.ini) to `c:\temp` (unfortunately, I have to use windows to programming in my work!);
2. Change all the data folder and all mysql folder;
3. So many restarts (for the sake the Windows way to exist);
4. Remove and reinstall MySQL in a different folder;
5. Change permissions to `full-controll` in tmpdir and mysql data folders;

Please, see my answer to know how I solved it.

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution

Finally, what solved the problem to me was: **change the index name!**

But wait, the name **was not repeated**! I had looked for it right in the first time! And it also **was not too long**! It was similar to others in the same script. It *had not special chars!** It was something like `IX_TAB_ABC_123`. So, **how in the world would somebody to guess what the problem was??**. For some reason, MySQL just *didn't like* the name I pick but it did not let me know why!!

#### My conclusion

When you make a software, please, dont be stupid! Put significative error messages on it! By "significative" I mean **clear** and **objective** error messages pointing the exact problem, the reason and, when possible, the solution. The world will be a better place if you just do it, believe me!

Hope it helps anybody else having this stupid problem!