# Start up Issue - Liferay 7.1.2 GA3 -javax.servlet.ServletException

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-dxp, liferay-7.1

I am facing issue in startup of Liferay 7.1.2 GA3 (CE)  with Mysql 5.7 db in Windows environment. It is restarted properly with hypersonic mode but connecting with mysql throws these error.

I tried downloading new tomcat and drop and recreate the db..etc. But it should not be an issue. Because i tried creating the tables manually , downloading the Portal DB from Liferay and executed. Still same issue.

```
    09 08:50:29.894 WARN  [http-nio-8080-exec-1][PortalImpl:6899] javax.servlet.ServletException: A servlet matching the filter (servlet.init.private=false)(servlet.type=friendly-url) is unavailable

javax.servlet.ServletException: A servlet matching the filter (servlet.init.private=false)(servlet.type=friendly-url) is unavailable
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ServletAdapter.service(ServletAdapter.java:91)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:119)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144)

2019-04-09 08:50:30.120 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-1][error_jsp:641] User ID null
2019-04-09 08:50:30.121 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-1][error_jsp:642] Current URL /
2019-04-09 08:50:30.122 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-1][error_jsp:643] Referer null
2019-04-09 08:50:30.123 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-1][error_jsp:644] Remote address 127.0.0.1
2019-04-09 08:50:30.123 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-1][error_jsp:646] com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.ActionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.ActionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.liferay.portal.events.ServicePreAction.run(ServicePreAction.java:1083)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.Action.processLifecycleEvent(Action.java:34)
    at com.liferay.portal.events.EventsProcessorUtil.process(EventsProcessorUtil.java:86)
    at com.liferay.portal.events.EventsProcessorUtil.process(EventsProcessorUtil.java:60)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.processServicePre(MainServlet.java:1169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:539)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.liferay.staging.security.internal.permission.StagingPermissionChecker.hasPermission(StagingPermissionChecker.java:134)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.permission.GroupPermissionImpl._contains(GroupPermissionImpl.java:226)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.permission.GroupPermissionImpl.contains(GroupPermissionImpl.java:103)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.permission.GroupPermissionUtil.contains(GroupPermissionUtil.java:51)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.permission.LayoutPermissionImpl.containsWithoutViewableGroup(LayoutPermissionImpl.java:277)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.permission.LayoutPermissionImpl.containsWithoutViewableGroup(LayoutPermissionImpl.java:319)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.permission.LayoutPermissionImpl.containsWithViewableGroup(LayoutPermissionImpl.java:333)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.permission.LayoutPermissionImpl._contains(LayoutPermissionImpl.java:595)
During the table creation, i got these warnings :

// WARN  [main][BaseDB:487] Error on rename of '.\lportal\#sql-116c_4.frm' to '.\lportal\assetcategory.frm' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied): create index IX_2008FACB on AssetCategory (groupId, vocabularyId);_ [Sanitized]


2019-04-15 08:34:20.006 WARN  [main][BaseDB:487] Error on rename of '.\lportal\#sql-116c_4.frm' to '.\lportal\dlfileentry.frm' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied): create index IX_BAF654E5 on DLFileEntry (groupId, fileEntryTypeId);_ [Sanitized]


2019-04-15 08:34:20.100 WARN  [main][BaseDB:487] Error on rename of '.\lportal\#sql-116c_4.frm' to '.\lportal\dlfileentry.frm' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied): create index IX_D20C434D on DLFileEntry (groupId, userId, folderId);_ [Sanitized]


2019-04-15 08:34:21.017 WARN  [main][BaseDB:487] Error on rename of '.\lportal\#sql-116c_4.frm' to '.\lportal\expandovalue.frm' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied): create index IX_B71E92D5 on ExpandoValue (tableId, rowId_);_ [Sanitized]


2019-04-15 08:34:21.252 WARN  [main][BaseDB:487] Error on rename of '.\lportal\#sql-116c_4.frm' to '.\lportal\group_.frm' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied): create unique index IX_AACD15F0 on Group_ (companyId, liveGroupId, groupKey);_ [Sanitized]


2019-04-15 08:34:21.321 WARN  [main][BaseDB:487] Error on rename of '.\lportal\#sql-116c_4.frm' to '.\lportal\group_.frm' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied): create index IX_7B590A7A on Group_ (type_, active_);_ [Sanitized]


2019-04-15 08:34:22.087 WARN  [main][BaseDB:487] Error on rename of '.\lportal\#sql-116c_4.frm' to '.\lportal\layoutrevision.frm' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied): create index IX_421223B1 on LayoutRevision (status);_ [Sanitized]


2019-04-15 08:34:22.853 WARN  [main][BaseDB:487] Error on rename of '.\lportal\#sql-116c_4.frm' to '.\lportal\portletpreferences.frm' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied): create index IX_A3B2A80C on PortletPreferences (ownerType, portletId);_ [Sanitized]


2019-04-15 08:34:23.519 WARN  [main][BaseDB:487] Error on rename of '.\lportal\#sql-116c_4.frm' to '.\lportal\resourcepermission.frm' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied): create index IX_A37A0588 on ResourcePermission (roleId);_ [Sanitized]


2019-04-15 08:34:23.675 WARN  [main][BaseDB:487] Error on rename of '.\lportal\#sql-116c_4.frm' to '.\lportal\role_.frm' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied): create index IX_5EB4E2FB on Role_ (subtype);_ [Sanitized]


2019-04-15 08:34:23.893 WARN  [main][BaseDB:487] Error on rename of '.\lportal\#sql-116c_4.frm' to '.\lportal\socialactivity.frm' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied): create index IX_1F00C374 on SocialActivity (mirrorActivityId, classNameId, classPK);_ [Sanitized]


2019-04-15 08:34:24.419 WARN  [main][BaseDB:487] Error on rename of '.\lportal\#sql-116c_4.frm' to '.\lportal\socialrequest.frm' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied): create index IX_CC86A444 on SocialRequest (userId, classNameId, classPK, type_, status);_ [Sanitized]




2019-04-15 08:34:25.013 WARN  [main][BaseDB:487] Error on rename of '.\lportal\#sql-116c_4.frm' to '.\lportal\usernotificationevent.frm' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied): create index IX_C4EFBD45 on UserNotificationEvent (userId, deliveryType, actionRequired, archived);_ [Sanitized]
```

I thought DB issue.So, Completely removed mysql server from windows system and reinstalled again. same issue
 I thought Bundle issue. so, downloaded latest 7.1 bundle (tried 7.2 also). same issue. To make sure that it is not any issue with mysql permission,i tried manually creating , altering tables and index....etc... , no issues with permission.

And i downloaded Liferay 6.2 with the same DB which works fine, issue with 7.X version with 5.7.

Is there issues related to windows environment or viruse software with Liferay 7.x? 
Related thread in liferay forum:
https://community.liferay.com/forums/-/message_boards/message/113084018

Comment: Try look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51373910/error-on-rename-x-frm-to-y-frm-errcode-13-permission-denied-mysql

Comment: Did you use the same DB for both Liferay 6.2 and 7.1?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to the "portal-ext.properties" file if the server has permissions to modify the indexes on the database:

database.indexes.update.on.startup=true

Answer (score 0):

I got same error while installing Liferay 7.2 , It worked fine after the following steps.

1. Started server with  default DB (Hypersonic)
2. Changed the DB details to mysql.
3. Configured jdk to the server.

Started the server it is working fine.

It was not working when I directly configured DB details in portal-ext.properties.